# Is there any app to add a keyboard shortcut to a mouse click on a specific location?

Tags: applications

Basically I have a program that I use to study and I need to be able to quickly choose between a 8 choice answer button. The program does not have inbuilt keyboard shortcuts. I need to answer a question every 2 seconds so moving the mouse around gets tiring if I could just associate where the buttons are to 1-8 on the keyboard that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try the TAB + Enter key. 
The TAB key should move the cursor to next question, the enter key should answer it.

Setting it up with 1-8 requires more doing, and you need to tell us what program are you using.

Answer (score 1):

Try saving scripts like this in AppleScript Editor and [assigning them shortcuts with FastScripts or other applications](https://superuser.com/questions/153890/assign-a-shortcut-to-running-a-script-in-os-x/264943#264943):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    click at {923, 186}
end tell

tell application "Safari" to tell document 1
    do JavaScript "document.querySelectorAll('#hmenus div ul li:nth-child(3) a')[0].click()"
end tell

tell application "Google Chrome" to tell tab 1 of window 1
    execute javascript "document.querySelectorAll('#hmenus div ul li:nth-child(3) a')[0].click()"
end tell
```

Another option would be to use [Keyboard Maestro](http://www.keyboardmaestro.com):

[image]